# From the code below, I would like to only have 1 of each letter. For e.g. 'send more money' should become sendmory. How would I achieve this?

Tags: c, command-line

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("USAGE: <porgram name> <word sum>");
        return 1;
    }


    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]); //prints the command line input
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Would i set the argv to a seperate array or would i just check the argv and if so, how?

from comment:
This is where i have gotten so far and the result is correct. Only problem is that i dont know how to get this result from the command line(argv)

```
char str[100];
int i, j, k;
printf("\n Please Enter any String : ");
scanf("%s", str);
for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
    for(j = i + 1; str[j] != '\0'; j++) {
        if(str[j] == str[i]) {
            for(k = j; str[k] != '\0'; k++) {
                str[k] = str[k + 1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before dealing with command line arguments, why don't you try to develop an algorithm to do what you want in a regular `char` array, and then modify it to accept command line arguments? Your previous question showed that you misunderstood what `argv` really is.

Comment: @aulven This is where i have gotten so far and the result is correct. Only problem is that i dont know how to get this result from the command line(argv)     char str[100];
   int i, j, k;
 
   printf("\n Please Enter any String :  ");
        scanf("%s", str);
     
   for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
   {
    for(j = i + 1; str[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
     if(str[j] == str[i])  
   {
      for(k = j; str[k] != '\0'; k++)
    {
     str[k] = str[k + 1];
    }
    }
  }
 }

Answer (score -1):

Now that you have posted your code (that is pretty good, but not quite there), here is  a snippet of virtually the same code, but with the addition that the terminating '\0' is also shifted to the left as characters are erased.

There are still hurdles like "how to 'pool together' multiple command line arguments?"

Keep at it... Perseverance brings rewards...

```
for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
    for( int ii = i + 1; ii < len; ii++ )
        if( str[i] == str[ii] ) {
            for( int iii = ii; ; iii++ )
                if( ( str[ iii ] = str[ iii + 1 ] ) == '\0' )
                    break;
            ii--;
            // Stay at same position to examine char shifted in
            // eg: "eat deer" => "eat der"...
            // Tricky...
            len--; // str has been shortened, too!
        }
```